# How to create a hierachical (e.g. CISCO-like) shell in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, shell, command-line-interface

I need to create an interactive shell for configuration purposes. Given the target market I'd love to provide something "familiar" to users. In this case this means an CISCO IOS like CLI interface with *hierarchical "contexts"*.

Up to now I only found [CLI::Console](https://github.com/davispuh/CLI-Console) which kind of does what I want but misses an important feature: The ability to create hierarchical namespaces of commands. So I'm wondering if there is another gem providing this functionality. Otherwise some hints to to address this with CLI::Console are highly appreciated.